# Could anyone explain to me how this function works?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Write a function capitals that takes a single string (word) as argument. The functions must return an ordered list containing the indexes of all capital letters in the string.

Example

```
Test.assertSimilar( capitals('CodEWaRs'), [0,3,4,6] );
```

My solution is this which is the simple for loop:

```
function capitals(word) {
    var ara = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        if(word[i] == word[i].toUpperCase()){
            ara.push(i)
        }
    }
    return ara;
}
```

But I want to understand this one using higher order function:

```
function capitals(word) {
    return word.split('').map(function(item, i) {
        return item == item.toUpperCase() ? i : null;
    }).filter(function(x) {
        return x != null;
    });
}
```

**especially the 'map(function(item, i)' part say why it knows i is the index without us defining it anywhere?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the index is known, as i, and is provided by map() along with the value and the whole collection. the function you pass to map gets called with 4 custom values given to it: arguments (value, index, collection), and a custom _this_, which is specified by a 2nd argument to map() itself.

Comment: Docs for `.map()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: if you return "" instead of null for the first map, the filter can be just .filter(String)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I understand the use of map better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code comments:

```
function capitals(word) {
  return word
          .split('')  // split a word in an array of letters
          .map(function(item, i) {
              // if letter is an upper case, return its index, null otherwise
              return item == item.toUpperCase() ? i : null;
          }).filter(function(x) {
              // filter out all null elements, effectively leaving only
              // indices of uppercase letters in a string.
              return x != null; 
          });
}
```

For an explanation of [map(), see this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The function passed to `map()` is a callback which is taking three arguments - the element from an array over which map() is called, an index of this element in the array and an array itself.

---

Here's an example of `map()` itself. Consider this code:

```
var result = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(function(element, index) {
  console.log('element ' + element + ' is at position: ' + index);
  return index % 2 === 0 ? element.toUpperCase() : element;
});

console.log(result);
```

It will print:

```
element a is at position: 0
element b is at position: 1
element c is at position: 2
element d is at position: 3 
['A', 'b', 'C', 'd']
```

Note that in this example we're using index parameter to capitalize only every other letter. Also note that `map()` would work with array of numbers, objects etc, not only letters.

Comment: Kamituel, so in that case we can pass any letter(i,j,k etc.)into the map function and it still refers to the index, correct?

Comment: @BRAYBRAY not sure I understand your question - I've updated an answer with some extra example. Does it help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the detailed explanation kamituel!really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

That's the beauty of `map`: you don't have to write your `for` loop, it's already in the body of the `map` function.

The body of `map` contains a for loop which declares the index and "injects" it into the function you passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

`map` applies a function to each element of the collection, in your case after `split` you have an array of chars, `item` is the current char and `i` is the index, the first operation:

```
return item == item.toUpperCase() ? i : null;
```

Is applied to all chars and reads, if this char is upper case return the index, else return `null` (this syntax `condition ? value : default` is called ternary operator).

The second is a filter to remove the null values from the array leaving only the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

> why it knows i is the index without us defining it anywhere?

It actually is defined, within the `map` function. For every item in the source array, it will provide three parameters to the `callback` function that you pass in. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> `callback`
>
> Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking three arguments:
>
> - `currentValue`
>   The current element being processed in array.
> - `index`
>   The index of the current element being processed in array.
> - `array`
>   The array map was called upon.